# Undefined Index error & Data not going to the database

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I really need your help, I'm trying to help a friend with her project. We've got two problems

The web form has multiple check boxes for a person to select the type of service they want.
If I check only one box and click submit I will get a "Notice: Undefined Index on lines 13 
thru 23 of the code. I am not sure how to resolve this, I have tried using the "if isset"
but not sure how to apply it to multiple check boxes,

The other problem here is when we select a check box and fill in the form for contact information
but no data is being written to the database.

Here is the php code

```
mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname);

$S_id= $_POST['s_id'];
$oral= $_POST['a'];
$lc= $_POST['b'];
$temp= $_POST['c'];
$adult= $_POST['d'];
$child= $_POST['e'];
$dent_rem= $_POST['f'];
$dent_por= $_POST['g'];
$jack_plastic= $_POST['h'];
$jack_por= $_POST['i'];
$brace= $_POST['j'];
$retainer= $_POST['k'];
$P_id= $_POST['p_id'];
$fname= $_POST['fname'];
$lname= $_POST['lname'];
$age= $_POST['age'];
$mobile= $_POST['mobile'];
$address= $_POST['address'];
$date= $_POST['date'];
if(isset ($_POST['a'])){ $oral= $_POST['a'];}


if ($oral== '' || $lc== '' || $temp== '' || $adult== '' || $child== '' || $dent_rem== '' ||       $dent_por== '' || $jack_plastic== '' ||
    $jack_por== '' || $brace== '' || $retainer== '' || $fname== '' || $lname== '' ||      $age== '' ||  $mobile== '' || $address== ''
|| $date== '' || $treatment== ''){

die('Error: ' . mysql_error());}

   else{

  $insert1= "INSERT INTO patient_info (P_id, first_name, last_name, age, mobile_num , address) 
  VALUES ('$id', '$fname', '$lname', '$age', '$mobile', '$address')";

  $insert2= "INSERT INTO services (S_id, oral_prophylaxis, lc_filling, temp_filling,              adult_extract, child_extract,
                            dental_removable, dental_porcelain, jacket_plastic, jacket_porcelain, braces, retainer, date) 
                            VALUES   ('$oral', '$lc', '$temp', '$adult','$child', '$dent_rem', '$dent_por', '$jack_plastic', '$jack_por',
                                    '$brace', '$retainer', '$date')";
    $count1 = mysql_query($insert1);
    $count2 = mysql_query($insert2);
  }

  /*
  $count1 = mysql_query($insert1);
  $count2 = mysql_query($insert2);

  if (($count1==0) && ($count2 == 0)){
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
else {
    header('location:index1.php');
}
   */
   ?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only checkboxes that are checked are sent to the server. All the other parameters will not be set. So you need to use `isset()`:

```
$oral = isset($_POST['a']) ? $_POST['a'] : '';
$lc= isset($_POST['b']) ? $_POST['b']: '';
...
```